# when focused remove underline from material entry control in xamarin forms for ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, material-design

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms.Material.iOS;
using MyApp.iOS;
using MyApp;
using UIKit;
using System.ComponentModel;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomMaterialEntry), typeof(CustomMaterialEntryRenderer), new[] { typeof(VisualMarker.MaterialVisual) })]

namespace MyApp.iOS
{
public class CustomMaterialEntryRenderer : MaterialEntryRenderer
{
/// <summary>
/// Element Changed Event
/// </summary>
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
{
base.OnElementChanged(e);

if (this.Control != null)
{
 UITextField UpdatedEntry = (UITextField)Control;
 UpdatedEntry.Background = null;
 UpdatedEntry.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
}
}
  protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
 {
  base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
  if (this.Control != null)
   this.Control.Underline.Color = UIColor.Clear;
  }
}
}
```

For android, it's working but when focused on the material entry in ios, it displays with the underline. please help me to remove the underline in ios for xamarin.forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the active underline height to `0f` :

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (this.Control != null)
        {
            Control.ActiveTextInputController.UnderlineHeightActive = 0f;
        }
    }
```